# How to remove metadata from image files using AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, script

I am using Catalina. I want to create an application using Applescript which which will remove metadata from dropped image files (onto its icon) using the unix utility exiftool.

I tried the following application in Automator but the AppleScript doesn't work (doesn't remove the metadata):

```
on open myFiles
    set bash_path_file to the POSIX path of myFiles
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -all= " & quoted form of bash_path_file
end open
```

I've researched many applescripts using google search and over here but none seem to work. So I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Great question. Solution from @user3439894 works perfectly too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an **ApplesScript** *droplet app*, save the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* in **Script Editor** as an *application*:

```
on open droppedItems
    repeat with droppedItem in droppedItems
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -all= " & ¬
            quoted form of POSIX path of droppedItem
    end repeat
end open
```

Now drag and drop the target file(s) onto the app's icon to process the file(s).

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>

Comment: This works perfectly. I've learned something!

Comment: So why isn't the script above not working with two options in the exiftool: do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -overwrite_original -all="